# Android ListActivity: onCreate is called every time after screen rotation, selected item resets, but visually remains checked

Tags: java, android, listview, screen-orientation, listactivity

A simple `ListActivity` containing a `TextView` and a `ListView` objects works fine if screen is not rotating.

**Problem description.** When running the app for the first time, `TextView myText` shows `-1`. It works. When clicking on different items `myText` sets/shows the value of the selected item id (or position). So, it works as well. On a certain moment, when for example item `Two` is selected and `myText` shows `2` I rotate the screen and `myText` becomes `-1` (because `onCreate` triggers again), so it means, the `ListView myList` clears selection, but item `Two` still remains selected (painted as a checked RadioButton). What's the problem? (P.S. Same thing happens to GridView).

Here is my source-code:

**activity_test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".TestActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_test" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

**content_test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/myText"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**TestActivity.java**

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends ListActivity {

    static String[] items = {"Zero", "One", "Two"};

    TextView myText;
    ListView myList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, items));

        myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myListViewSelectedText);
        myText.setText(String.valueOf(myList.getSelectedItemPosition()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        myText.setText(String.valueOf(position));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
  <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: Bad idea. As documentation says - it's last resort option and using this attribute should avoided. More info here: [Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) find configChanges description.

Answer (score 1):

When a configuration change occurs, all activities will be recreated to ensure that the correct resources are used.

One way to preserve the state that you need, is to override `onSaveInstanceState()` putting all data you want to the provided `Bundle` parameter. Then, when the activity gets recreated, you can extract the saved values from the provided `Bundle` parameter in `onCreate()`.

Just save the index of the selected list element, and then set it back when recreating.

Answer (score 1):

Saving instance is more complicated process, @danail-alexiev is correct, in some cases you've save data manually and than restore it.

But why Checkbox stays checked? In short it's because it has own implementation of `onSaveInstanceState` that handles it. And there is some magic that calls it and map this Parcelable data with view id. You can do simple experiment, create empty app, in layout add EditText, without id - run it, put some text, change orientation, boom - data missing. Then retry with id.

You can find great explanation here: [Saving instance state](http://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/)